# date.js simple way to determine if time specified in parse

Tags: javascript, datejs

Using ***date.js*'s `Date.parse`** what's the simplest way to determine whether a user input string, e.g. *'oct 31 12am'* vs just *'oct 31'*, includes a time value, i.e. whether a time was explicitly specified or not.

Comment: Tell users acceptable formats, then validate their input. If it doesn't comply, tell them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far but the question is specifically about using date.js's parser, and simply wanting to know whether the parsed string explicitly included a time or not.  Anyone with intimate knowledge of date.js could respond.

Comment: You should use the tool that is best suited to the job. You post a question, others respond. How you determine "best" is up to you, but if your sole criterion for evaluation is "it must use date.js" you are likely ignoring answers that meet other criteria such as "do the job" or "are effective".

Comment: Thanks for that pragmatism, but in this case, 'do the job' and 'are effective' require that the solution use date.js parser. Which is why I specified the question that way.

Comment: Apparently data.js meets neither of those criteria. So if it can't be done with date.js, but can using a simple RegExp, you'll ignore the regular expression solution and just give up?

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression to check if the user has entered am or pm, if not give them a message saying it must be included

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str= $("#date_input").val; 
var patt1=/am|pm/gi;
if (!str.match(patt1)){
     $("#message").text("you must include a time in either 'am' or 'pm' format");
}

</script>
```